# Lenovo ideapad FLEX 4-1130 Install

Tags: system-installation, lenovo

My Lenovo ideapad FLEX 4-1130 does not progress past the GRUB2 screen using either UEFI or BIOS modes. In either instance selecting any of the boot options (live, install, oem install, checkdisk) results in a black screen or black screen with a frozen cursor.

I have turned off secure boot, and enabled legacy support. I've also reviewed as much information related to the problem as I can find, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You did correct steps, now all you need is to Turn Off UEFI option in BIOS settings. You have enabled Legacy but didn't disabled UEFI. That is the only reason.

Finally, make sure when you boot from bootable USB, select Legacy Boot option.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

allow usb boot change to efi or legacy, remember ( legacy first) secure boot or not should work. after bootin go back to boot settings if necessary and change the boot order. pick your SD or usb to go first one has the installation on it... same problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement is to disable secureboot. You can/should leave uefi booting on. You do not necessarily need legacy support.